# model inheritance error in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-2

I am trying the following code but keep getting the this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method
>   news_model::get_db_message()

in my application/core/My_Model.php

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function get_db_meesage() {
        echo "bla";
    }
}
```

this is my news_model.php

```
class news_model extends MY_Model {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function delete_news($news_id) {
        $this->get_db_message();
    }
}
```

I felt it is probably a very subtle error but I just can't figure this out..

Comment: have you checked the class extension prefix is set correctly to MY_ in the config.php (about line 109)

Comment: yes, it is set to 'MY_'.

Comment: Have you tried making the class declaration start with a capital letter? E.g. class News_model extends MY_Model {...} Is the news model being loaded? Also can you show the code in the controller calling the model?

Comment: That was it. changed classname to News_model and updated it's name in controller worked. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Correct answer taken from comments.*

Codeigniter expects classes to start with a capital letter. This is stated in their [General Style and Syntax](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html) document.

To quote:

> **Class and Method Naming**
>
> Class names should always start with an
> uppercase letter. Multiple words should be separated with an
> underscore, and not CamelCased. All other class methods should be
> entirely lowercased and named to clearly indicate their function,
> preferably including a verb. Try to avoid overly long and verbose
> names.
>
> INCORRECT: *class superclass* , *class SuperClass*
>
> CORRECT: **class Super_class**

Answer (score 0):

```
public function get_db_meesage() {
    echo "bla";
}

PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method news_model::get_db_message()



get_db_message() 

get_db_meesage()
```